# Error while adding service reference for a wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am getting an error when i try to add a service reference of a WCF service. Error details is below. My web service is hosted on a different server and my client is on different server. When i run the service directly from IE i can see the service but adding it in .net web application i get error. Please advise

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://193.11.33.66/coverscanservice/DownloadCoverScan.svc'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status
>   503: Service Unavailable. Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be
>   resolved:
>   'http://193.11.33.66/coverscanservice/DownloadCoverScan.svc'.
>   The HTTP service located at
>   http://193.11.33.66/coverscanservice/DownloadCoverScan.svc
>   is too busy.  The remote server
>   returned an error: (503) Server
>   Unavailable. If the service is defined
>   in the current solution, try building
>   the solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

Comment: Is the server on a windows domain and/or have windows integrated authentication turned on?

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the properties of the application pool assigned to this service, you can turn off the rapid fail protection for this pool with the checkbox. This may alleviate the 503 error but it won't diagnose your true problem.

You'll need to install the [windows debugging tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) and/or [Debug Diagnostics for IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&displaylang=en) in order to find the true source of the problem. Something is causing your w3wp.exe process to crash repeatedly, and it can't recover. Also, check your event log for items related to the w3wp.exe stopping unexpectedly. There may be helpful information there.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP .NET Web Application after Adding the WCF Webservice reference .Right click on that reference check the Configure Service Reference change setting like in collection type set "System.collection.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection".Also change Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies set "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" .

After that Build the project Call the Service Methods used it and Run it.